# Javascript, dynamic color HTML inputbox if value insert is included in range

Tags: javascript, php, variables, range

Good Afternoon,
I need to check if the value insert by the user inside an inputbox on my PHP page it's included in specific range. So if the value insert isn't included in this range i need to color the text in the inputbox or show a message. The range is definited from two PHP variables.

For example if my range will be >10 and <20 any number from 11 to 19 will be 'ok' and any another number (out of this range) will be colored in red or something like this.

I tried to use something like this:

```
<script>
function checkFilled() {
var inputVal = document.getElementById("myinputbox");
var min = "<?php echo $someVar2; ?>";
var max = "<?php echo $someVar3; ?>";
    
if (inputVal.value < min) {
inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
} 
else if (inputVal.value > max) {
inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}    
else {
inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "";
}
}

checkFilled();
</script>
```

PHP:

```
$someVar2 = 10;
$someVar3 = 20;
echo '<input type="text" id="myinputbox" onchange="checkFilled();">';
```

This way doesn't work and all number I insert in my inputbox will be change the color to yellow. If I try to set the min and the max variable with a number directly in Javascript (without reading the variable from PHP) the script work.

Could anyone please help me?

Thanks you very much for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Good Afternoon
you can go this way

```
<input type="text" id="myinputbox" oninput="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var inputVal = document.getElementById("myinputbox").value;
  var min = "<?php echo $someVar2; ?>";
  var max = "<?php echo $someVar3; ?>";
  if (inputVal.value < min) {
    document.getElementById("myinputbox").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  } 
  else if (inputVal.value > max) {
    document.getElementById("myinputbox").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }    
  else {
    document.getElementById("myinputbox").style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}
</script>
```

you have to use `oninput` event and try debugging you will get it
All the best